# How to get Yoga places nearby me in Android?

Tags: android

I am using Google Places API to search nearby places. As per that document there is no  place_types to search Yoga places. I need yoga places. How to find nearby places which are not the in the list? Thank you.

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: I think yoga places are a sub category of gym! You should find gyms and filter them by their sport field info.

Comment: then how can search for govt. tourism centre

Comment: just playing with information my friends project for university is same as your application he gather information from google and analyze them by simple AI (its not so simple) you should struggle with information

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it :

```
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34,-118&radius=1000&type=gym&keyword=yoga&key=AIzaSyBsqqvSXgfdba5wWPx2YGTJvyWg4UUUsCM
```

The following example is a search request for places of type 'gym' within a 1000m radius of a point in Los Angeles, USA, containing the word 'yoga'.

If you found a better solution, please let us know. Hope this helps you. Good luck.